# How to Change Background/Foregound color from a different Window

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to Create a dark mode Check Box in my options Menu.
I don't know how to point my code to my MainWindow.

That's my code in OptionsWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void DarkModeCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             Background = Brushes.Black;
             MLblTelnetStatus.Foreground = Brushes.White;
             telnet.Foreground = Brushes.White;
             ChatView.Background = Brushes.Black;
             ChatView.Foreground = Brushes.White;

            }
```

Backgound,Foregound etc. are all in my MainWindow.xaml

I know how to do it From my MainWindow but I want to move the checkbox to my Options